# How to declare a System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary in powershell

Tags: powershell, interface, idictionary

In Powershell I need to pass an input to a method of type *System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary[string, system.object]*.

Could someone please help me with a sample code on how IDictionary[string,system.object] could be declared and value is set to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
$dict = New-Object 'system.collections.generic.dictionary[[string],[object]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to that given in [Andrey Marcheuk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37161186/444244).

```
$dict = [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string,object]]::new()
```

A less expressive way but quite concise is an empty hashtable.

```
$dict = @{}
```

From which follows a way to set up data.

```
$dict = @{"badger"="Mustelidae"; "tiger"="Panthera"; "snake"="Serpentes"}
```

A single value can be added or updated.

```
$dict.badger = "Mustelidae"
```

Comment: much cleaner than using a `New-Object` plus a string representation